# OPE Coefficients in Holography

Tags: conformal-field-theory, ads-cft

I am having trouble reproducing a calculation from the paper ["Holography from Conformal Field Theory"](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.0151).

In a 2d CFT, consider an operator $\mathcal{O}$ in mean field theory (MFT) with conformal dimension $\Delta$. In MFT, the only primaries that contribute to the $\mathcal{O} \times \mathcal{O}$ OPE are the identity and the double-trace operators $[\mathcal{O} \mathcal{O}]_{n\ell}$, which have dimensions $2\Delta + 2n + \ell$. It follows that the 4-point function of $\mathcal{O}$ has the following conformal block decomposition, as in equation (3.4) of the paper:

\begin{equation}
\langle \mathcal{O}(\infty) \mathcal{O}(1) \mathcal{O}(z, \bar{z}) \mathcal{O}(0) \rangle = \frac{1}{|z|^{2\Delta}} + \sum_{n\ell} p_{n\ell} |g_{n\ell}(z)|^2. \tag{1}
\end{equation}

Here $p_{n\ell}$ are squares of OPE coefficients, and $g_{n\ell}$ are conformal blocks. I am working in the semiclassical limit (i.e. $c \gg 1$), and I assume that $\mathcal{O}$ is light (i.e. $\Delta$ does not scale with $c$). The first term on the RHS is the contribution of the identity operator. The conformal blocks $g_{n\ell}(z)$ are hypergeometric in nature: see section 3.3 on p. 11 for the details, in particular equations (3.5) and (3.6). Because $\mathcal{O}$ is a generalized free field, its 4-point function reduces to products of 2-point functions via Wick's theorem. The result is equation (4.1) in the paper:

\begin{equation}
\langle \mathcal{O}(\infty) \mathcal{O}(1) \mathcal{O}(z, \bar{z}) \mathcal{O}(0) \rangle = \frac{1}{|z|^{2\Delta}} + \frac{1}{|1-z|^{2\Delta}} + 1. \tag{2}
\end{equation}

My goal is to set (1) and (2) equal to each other in order to extract the OPE coefficients $p_{n\ell}$ in MFT. After stripping off the vacuum term $1/|z|^{2\Delta}$ from both sides, the paper states:

> By Taylor expanding the conformal partial wave expansion (3.4) around $z, \bar{z} = 0$ one finds that
> \begin{equation}
> p_0(n, l) = \big[1 + (-1)^{l} \big] C_n C_{n+l}, \qquad
> C_n = \frac{\Gamma^2(\Delta + n) \Gamma(2\Delta + n - 1)}{n! \Gamma^2(\Delta) \Gamma(2\Delta + 2n - 1)}. \tag{4.2}
> \end{equation}

I am confused about how this result was obtained. Each of the conformal blocks in (1) has a nontrivial Taylor series in $z, \bar{z}$, so in order to match the LHS and the RHS order by order, one should Taylor-expand both sides as follows:

\begin{equation}
1 + \frac{1}{|1 - z|^{2\Delta}} = \sum_{n\ell} p_{n\ell} |g_{n\ell}(z)|^2 \iff 1 + \sum_{m,m' = 0}^{\infty} a^{(m,m')} z^m \bar{z}^{m'} = \sum_{n\ell} p_{n\ell} \sum_{m,m' = 0}^{\infty} b_{n\ell}^{(m,m')} z^m \bar{z}^{m'}. \tag{3}
\end{equation}

Here $a^{(m,m')} = \frac{\Gamma(\Delta + m)\Gamma(\Delta + m')}{\Gamma^2(\Delta) m! m'!}$ are the binomial coefficients for $1/|1-z|^{2\Delta}$, and $b_{n\ell}^{(m,m')}$ are the Taylor coefficients of the conformal block $|g_{n\ell}(z)|^2$ at order $z^m \bar{z}^{m'}$, also expressible as ratios of Gamma functions. It follows by matching the coefficients at each order that
\begin{equation}
a^{(m,m')} = \sum_{n\ell} p_{n\ell} b_{n\ell}^{(m,m')} \qquad (m,m') \neq (0,0). \tag{4}
\end{equation}
The fact that the $g_{n\ell}(z)$ have nontrivial Taylor series causes the OPE coefficients $p_{n\ell}$ to appear in complicated linear combinations at each order $z^m \bar{z}^{m'}$ in the Taylor expansion of the 4-point function. To extract the $p_{n\ell}$, one would have to solve the linear system (4). If this is what the authors of the paper have done, I cannot see how it can be done in closed form. In any case, **I would appreciate any guidance in reproducing equation (4.2) in the paper.**

Comment: To get enough OPE coefficients to get a pattern, the most efficient brute force method is the lightcone expansion. I.e. u goes to 0 and then v goes to 1. The good methods to actually prove this result came later and are referred to as the Euclidean and Lorentzian inversion formulae.